# Apache2 doesn't show PHP code

Tags: php, apache, debian, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I want to use my Raspi as a webserver so I followed [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Raspberry-Pi-Web-Server) guide that basically set me up with an apache server and accompanying php modules. This works for html webpages.
The config file seems to suggest this module is being loaded by the apache server, but obviously something is going wrong since some test.php file:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

fails to produce any output. I have reinstalled apache and have verified the (as far as I can see) correct url's to  but to no avail.

How do I get to see my precious php info?

Obviously I will supply required information.

Comment: What do you see in access log files? Have you rebooted apache after installing php?

Comment: the access log file (at /var/log/apache2/access.log) doesn't show anything related to said php page. I did restart my apache (and re-installed it, for that matter:))

Answer (score 0):

In order to run php script with Apache web server, you have to install php package in your server and libapache module which is required by apache to run php scripts. You can use following command to install php

```
sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: this was suggested by guide I've linked to, doesn't help.

Comment: @Wokkelsok Does loading test.php file in browser show the code or does it show a blank page?

Comment: Does something comes up in the apache error log (/var/log/apache2/error.log)?

Answer (score 0):

I've replalced the flashdrive with a clean raspbian and retried the process, and for some reason this time I do get the desired output. I have no idea what happened there.